# How to get data from a specific reference in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database with the next structure:

> PPostdb-e1e1d
>
> > Datos
> >
> > > USERID
> > >
> > > > name
> > > >
> > > > mail
> > > >
> > > > USERID
> >
> > Post
> >
> > > PostTITLE
> > >
> > > > PostTITLE
> > > >
> > > > text

I'm developing an app for publish simple post, before I added the option to publish a post, I was getting the user's data and showing it in an activity using the nex code:

```
 mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
```

...

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showPersonalData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

private void showPersonalData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID=user.getUid().toString();
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
        uInfo.setNAME(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getNAME());
        uInfo.setMAIL(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getMAIL());


        name.setText(uInfo.getNAME());
        mail.setText(uInfo.getMAIL());

    }
```

But now when someone publish a post, I can't get the user's data and show it in my activity for that information, when I try to open that activity, it stop working.

How can I solve that problem? I think is an error in the Reference, but I can't solve it.

Comment: If the activity stops working, there is likely an exception and a stack trace. Please edit your question to include those.

Comment: A quick first guess is that you need `myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().getChild("Datos");`